# multiple buttons in appbar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I'm afraid I'm missing something simple here, but I'm trying to put multiple buttons in my app bar.

here's the code for the initial app bar

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button  x:Name="resetButton" Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="resetButton_Click" />
    </AppBar>
</common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>
```

Now this code works, but I want to add a second button.

I thought that this would be fairly simple to do, I attempted:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar HorizontalAlignment="Left"> <!-- line 19 -->
        <Button  x:Name="resetButton" Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="resetButton_Click" />
        <Button  x:Name="newButton" Content="NewButton" />  <!-- line 21 -->
    </AppBar>
</common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>
```

but I get the following errors:

```
The property "Content" can only be set once. (line 19)
The property "Content" can only be set once. (line 21)
Duplication assignment to the 'Content' property of the 'AppBar' object (line 21)
```

I think there might perhaps be something to the `AppBar` control that I'm missing.  How do i put a second button in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put everything in a `StackPanel` in `AppBar`

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar HorizontalAlignment="Left"> <!-- line 19 -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button  x:Name="resetButton" Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="resetButton_Click" />
            <Button  x:Name="newButton" Content="NewButton" />  <!-- line 21 -->
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>
```

For better control, you could use a `Grid` which will allow you to have content on both sides:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="LeftPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <!-- Left Content here -->
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="RightPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <!-- Right Content here -->
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I am going to accept your answer in 6 minutes.  have to wait 15

Comment: If taking this approach there's no need to put `"50*"` when `"*"` will be the same thing. Besides - I'd recommend putting 1 side `"*"` and the other side `"Auto"` depending on which side you're primarily going to use so that it will adapt to use more than half of the space if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm still learning how to use XAML and the result "looked like expected" :)

Comment: It works. I'm not saying you're wrong, just providing some insight/suggestions. Welcome!

Comment: That's exactly why this site exists in this format, thanks for the info and I updated the code accordingly

Answer (score 3):

You are setting content twice which is exactly what the error says. Instead, set the content to something that accepts multiple children like a `StackPanel', like so:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar HorizontalAlignment="Left"> <!-- line 19 -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button  x:Name="resetButton" Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="resetButton_Click" />
            <Button  x:Name="newButton" Content="NewButton" />  <!-- line 21 -->
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>
```